# angularjs input date ng-model binding cannot show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my situation:
I use $uibModal pass an object "check" into modal popup window.
Each data shows up except the date. There is nothing wrong with the modal or other codes since I can just display the date under the title "Edit", as you can see on the picture. (seems object successfully passed into the modal and no data is lost).
 I guess there is something wrong with the " input type date " and the html.
[image]
[image]

If I set the date in the popup window, save it, and then open up it again, the date shows. Confused. Please help me out.

Comment: What are the contents of `singlecheck.Date`?

Comment: Please don't include pictures of your code, include the code itself. Stack Overflow has very nice code formatting. Including your code makes it easier for someone else to fiddle around w/your problem and will help other people having the same issue in the future.

Comment: Browsers do not currently have a uniform support for the date and time input types and the corresponding widgets (http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime), so it would probably be a better idea to use the text input type and use date/timepickers (like the ones in Angular UI Bootstrap) to provide the widgets.